# Date.getTimezoneOffset inverted?

Tags: javascript, date, timezone-offset

I have a JSON response from my server giving me UTC Unix timestamps in seconds.  I'm parsing that into JavaScript dates that will be used in a chart (displaying the time in the user's locale).

I obviously have to coax the timestamp I have (in UTC) into the browser's locale, so I wrote a function that creates a new `Date` in the browser's locale, calls `getTimezoneOffset()` on it to get the "offset in minutes" in the current locale, as per [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), converts both to milliseconds, and returns the sum.  Now I have a JavaScript friendly Unix timestamp in the user's locale.

However, I don't.

as it turns out, `(new Date()).getTimezoneOffset()` returns (positive) 300 in GMT-5 and -120 in GMT+2.  Why is the offset inverted?  I would have expected the offset to match the sign of the timezone - ie: I need to subtract 300 minutes to get to GMT-5, and ADD 120 minutes to get to GMT+2.  Instead, I have to subtract the values that are returned by `getTimezoneOffset`

Comment: See the description [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset).`This means that the offset is positive if the local timezone is behind UTC and negative if it is ahead.`

Comment: so if I'd actually clicked through to the method...... *facepalm*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nope.

The [spec (§15.9.5.26)](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_15.9.5.26) says:

> **15.9.5.26   Date.prototype.getTimezoneOffset ( )**
>
> Returns the difference between local time and UTC time in minutes.
>
> 1. Let *t* be this time value.
> 2. If *t* is NaN, return NaN.
> 3. Return (*t* − LocalTime(t)) / *msPerMinute*.

Comment: so, basically a RTFM issue.  Maybe too little caffeine on my part.  Well, at least it's documented :D.  Thanks